# how to download an url image in flutter?

Tags: flutter

I was looking for how to download an image and I found a code here in stack, however when testing it in my application it gives me an error, someone could help me with this
[image]

```
_notificationImage(String urlImage, String title, String author, int index) async {
    //comment out the next two lines to prevent the device from getting
    // the image from the web in order to prove that the picture is 
    // coming from the device instead of the web.
    var response = await get(urlImage); // <--2
    var documentDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    var firstPath =  documentDirectory.path +"/test_audio" + "/images";
    var filePathAndName = documentDirectory.path  + '/images/pic.jpg'; 
    // comment out the next three lines to prevent the image from being saved
    // to the device to show that it's coming from the internet
    Directory(firstPath).create(recursive: true);
      File file2 = File(filePathAndName);             // <-- 2
      file2.writeAsBytesSync(response.bodyBytes);         // <-- 3
        
      setState(() {
      imageNotification = filePathAndName;
      dataLoaded = true;
    }); // <-- 1
    
      _showNotificationMediaStyle(
        imageNotification,
        title,
        author
      );
  }
```

Comment: try this: https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/images/cached-images

Comment: I need the image to show it in a multimedia notification with the local notification package, this package is to show it in the front of the application and the local notification package in the image asks me for a String bitmap if you could explain to me how to use an image from the internet for a notification in flutter I would appreciate it